# How can I use UUIDs in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Is there a way to define a column (primary key) as a [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) in [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) if using [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/) (Postgres)?

Comment: Unfortunately [Backend-agnostic GUID Type](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/custom_types.html?highlight=guid#backend-agnostic-guid-type) from the SQLAlchemy documentation for column types does not seem to work for primary keys in SQLite database engines. Not quite as ecumenical as I was hoping for.

Comment: SQLAlchemy utils provides [UUIDType decorator](https://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/sqlalchemy_utils/types/uuid.html), there's no need to reinvent the wheel

Comment: @FilipeBezerradeSousa One caveat is that you might need to change `value.hex` in the line `return value.bytes if self.binary else value.hex` in the [UUIDType decorator source](https://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/sqlalchemy_utils/types/uuid.html) to `str(value)`, otherwise comparing to a UUID literal object inside `.where()` will fail. E.g., without this change, a query such as `select(table.c).where(table.c.uuid == UUID("bb89641d-64c4-4433-975a-0085d737a5fb"))`. (Assuming there actually is a row with such a UUID.)

Answer (score 334):

The sqlalchemy postgres dialect supports UUID columns.  This is easy (and the question is specifically postgres) -- I don't understand why the other answers are all so complicated.

Here is an example:

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import UUID
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import uuid

db = SQLAlchemy()

class Foo(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
```

Be careful not to miss passing the `callable` `uuid.uuid4` into the column definition, rather than calling the function itself with `uuid.uuid4()`. Otherwise, you will have the same scalar value for all instances of this class. More details [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.default):

> A scalar, Python callable, or ColumnElement expression representing the default value for this column, which will be invoked upon insert if this column is otherwise not specified in the VALUES clause of the insert.

Comment: I totally agree with you. Some of the other answers are cool for other databases, but for postgres this is the cleanest solution. (You can also set a default as `uuid.uuid4`).

Comment: In my view, this is by far the best answer here. The top voted one builds on the MySQL dialect ...

Comment: Can you provide a MWE?  Or maybe the serializer in flask_sqlalchemy understands the UUID type?  The code in the pastebin below errors,
https://pastebin.com/hW8KPuYw

Comment: nevermind, if you want to use UUID objects from stdlib, do `Column(UUID(as_uuid=True) ...)`

Comment: Thank you! It might be nice if `Column` and `Integer` were imported at the top of the code snippet, or were changed to read `db.Column` and `db.Integer`

Comment: Postgres seems to support UUID natively. if `as_uuid` is set to True, when a result from the db is processed the code tries to execute something like `uuid.UUID(uuid.uuid4())` which it raise an exception. Then, more care has to be taken to set `as_uuid`.

Comment: is it necessary to specify ``nullable=False`` when you’ve already set ``primary_key=True`` ?

Comment: No there's no need @nephanth

Comment: Does the `default` callable get run when an instance of class is created, or when it's committed to the database?

Answer (score 71):

[I wrote this](http://blog.sadphaeton.com/2009/01/19/sqlalchemy-recipeuuid-column.html) and the domain is gone but here's the guts....

Regardless of how my colleagues who really care about proper database design feel about UUID's and GUIDs used for key fields. I often find I need to do it. I think it has some advantages over autoincrement that make it worth it.

I've been refining a UUID column type for the past few months and I think I've finally got it solid.

```
from sqlalchemy import types
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.base import MSBinary
from sqlalchemy.schema import Column
import uuid


class UUID(types.TypeDecorator):
    impl = MSBinary
    def __init__(self):
        self.impl.length = 16
        types.TypeDecorator.__init__(self,length=self.impl.length)

    def process_bind_param(self,value,dialect=None):
        if value and isinstance(value,uuid.UUID):
            return value.bytes
        elif value and not isinstance(value,uuid.UUID):
            raise ValueError,'value %s is not a valid uuid.UUID' % value
        else:
            return None

    def process_result_value(self,value,dialect=None):
        if value:
            return uuid.UUID(bytes=value)
        else:
            return None

    def is_mutable(self):
        return False


id_column_name = "id"

def id_column():
    import uuid
    return Column(id_column_name,UUID(),primary_key=True,default=uuid.uuid4)

# Usage
my_table = Table('test',
         metadata,
         id_column(),
         Column('parent_id',
            UUID(),
            ForeignKey(table_parent.c.id)))
```

I believe storing as binary(16 bytes) should end up being more efficient than the string representation(36 bytes?), And there seems to be some indication that indexing 16 byte blocks should be more efficient in mysql than strings. I wouldn't expect it to be worse anyway.

One disadvantage I've found is that at least in phpymyadmin, you can't edit records because it implicitly tries to do some sort of character conversion for the "select * from table where id =..." and there's miscellaneous display issues.

Other than that everything seems to work fine, and so I'm throwing it out there. Leave a comment if you see a glaring error with it. I welcome any suggestions for improving it.

Unless I'm missing something the above solution will work if the underlying database has a UUID type. If it doesn't, you would likely get errors when the table is created. The solution I came up with I was targeting MSSqlServer originally and then went MySql in the end, so I think my solution is a little more flexible as it seems to work fine on mysql and sqlite. Haven't bothered checking postgres yet.

Comment: yeah I posted it after I saw referrals from Jacob's answer.

Comment: Note that if you're using version 0.6 or greater, the MSBinary import statement in Tom's solution should be changed to "from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.base import MSBinary".  Source: http://www.mail-archive.com/sqlalchemy@googlegroups.com/msg18397.html

Comment: "I wrote this" is a dead link.

Comment: See also [the UUIDType that ships with SQLAlchemy-utils](http://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/data_types.html#module-sqlalchemy_utils.types.uuid)

Comment: How do you set this up so you can compare for equality against a UUID string? Is it enough to override `__eq__`? E.g. when comparing against a string provided in a REST request: `if user.id == user_id: ...`

Comment: The comment of @CalJacobson is very useful; I propose to adjust this in the example code

Comment: i updated the example to reflect sqlalchemy's updates

Comment: How would one target postgresql?

Comment: @codeninja postgresql already has a native UUID type, so just use `sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.UUID` directly. see [Backend-agnostic GUID Type](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/custom_types.html#backend-agnostic-guid-type)

Comment: also, as of python 2.6, instead of invoking `TypeDecorator.__init__()` I believe you should call `super(UUID, self).__init__()`. (But it's possible that `TypeDecorator` was not a new-style class in back in 2010).

Answer (score 43):

If you are happy with a 'String' column having UUID value, here goes a simple solution:

```
def generate_uuid():
    return str(uuid.uuid4())

class MyTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'my_table'

    uuid = Column(String, name="uuid", primary_key=True, default=generate_uuid)
```

Comment: Don't store UUID as string unless you are using a really weird database that doesn't support them.  otherwise, maybe store all of your data as strings... ;)

Comment: @Nick why? whats the downside?

Comment: @rayepps - there are many downsides - a few off the top of mind: size - string uuid takes up twice the space - 16bytes vs 32 chars - not including any formatters.  Processing time - more bytes = more processing time by the CPU as your dataset gets bigger.  uuid string formats differ by language, adding addition required translations.  Easier for someone to misuse the column, as you can put anything in there, things that aren't uuids.  That should be enough to start.

Comment: You should not use Strings as columns for a uuid, for performance issues. A Binary(16) is more recommended.

Comment: Does sqlite qualify as a "really weird database"? :P

Comment: I am storing thousands strings as data, having one more field as string doesn't scare me.

Answer (score 26):

I've used the `UUIDType` from the [`SQLAlchemy-Utils` package](http://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/data_types.html#module-sqlalchemy_utils.types.uuid).

Comment: I'm currently trying to use this, problem is I get an error: 
`raise InvalidStatus("notfound: {k}. (cls={cls})".format(k=k, cls=cls))`

`alchemyjsonschema.InvalidStatus: notfound: BINARY(16). (cls=<class 'sqlalchemy_utils.types.uuid.UUIDType'>)`

Comment: Have you guys received the error: `NameError: name 'sqlalchemy_utils' is not defined`?

Comment: `SQLAlchemy-Utils` is a third-party package, you need to install it first: `pip install sqlalchemy-utils`

Comment: This is the way to go, although your migrations need to account or systems that have UUID vs CHAR/BINARY values for uuids.

Answer (score 18):

Since you're using Postgres this should work:

```py
from app.main import db
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import UUID

class Foo(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
```

Comment: This should be the only accepted answer for those developers using a PostgreSQL database.

Comment: This is a duplicated version of JDiMatteo's answer.

Answer (score 18):

SQLAlchemy 2.0 adds the [UUID type](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.UUID), the SQL-native form of the database agnostic type which is backwards compatible with the previous PostgreSQL-only version of UUID.

Example:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, Mapped

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

class MyModel(Base):
    my_field: Mapped[sa.UUID]
```

Comment: This answer needs more upvotes since it's not specific to just postgres

Comment: Or to support databases that don't implement `UUID` specifically, you can use the `sqlalchemy.Uuid` type which will use `UUID` on databases that support it, and fall back to `CHAR(32)` for those that don't (e.g. Sqlite).
Useful in my case using `sqlite` for testing, and `postgres` for production.

Answer (score 8):

Here is an approach based on the [Backend agnostic GUID](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/custom_types.html?highlight=guid#backend-agnostic-guid-type) from the SQLAlchemy docs, but using a BINARY field to store the UUIDs in non-postgresql databases.

```
import uuid

from sqlalchemy.types import TypeDecorator, BINARY
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import UUID as psqlUUID

class UUID(TypeDecorator):
    """Platform-independent GUID type.

    Uses Postgresql's UUID type, otherwise uses
    BINARY(16), to store UUID.

    """
    impl = BINARY

    def load_dialect_impl(self, dialect):
        if dialect.name == 'postgresql':
            return dialect.type_descriptor(psqlUUID())
        else:
            return dialect.type_descriptor(BINARY(16))

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        if value is None:
            return value
        else:
            if not isinstance(value, uuid.UUID):
                if isinstance(value, bytes):
                    value = uuid.UUID(bytes=value)
                elif isinstance(value, int):
                    value = uuid.UUID(int=value)
                elif isinstance(value, str):
                    value = uuid.UUID(value)
        if dialect.name == 'postgresql':
            return str(value)
        else:
            return value.bytes

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        if value is None:
            return value
        if dialect.name == 'postgresql':
            return uuid.UUID(value)
        else:
            return uuid.UUID(bytes=value)
```

Comment: What would the usage of this be?

Comment: One scenario where you may want to support two different implementations of UUID (or any other type) would be when you are using one DB for production and one for tests. For instance, UUID in postgresql is a native type, but when writing tests you may use an in memomry sqlite DB that does not have the native UUID and needs the fallback.

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone is interested, I've been using Tom Willis answer, but found useful to add a string to uuid.UUID conversion in the process_bind_param method

```
class UUID(types.TypeDecorator):
    impl = types.LargeBinary

    def __init__(self):
        self.impl.length = 16
        types.TypeDecorator.__init__(self, length=self.impl.length)

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect=None):
        if value and isinstance(value, uuid.UUID):
            return value.bytes
        elif value and isinstance(value, basestring):
            return uuid.UUID(value).bytes
        elif value:
            raise ValueError('value %s is not a valid uuid.UUId' % value)
        else:
            return None

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect=None):
        if value:
            return uuid.UUID(bytes=value)
        else:
            return None

    def is_mutable(self):
        return False
```

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same issue, this should work, it works for me:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, text
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import UUID

Column(
    "id", UUID(as_uuid=True),
    primary_key=True,
    server_default=text("gen_random_uuid()"),
)
```

If you use PostgreSQL < 14, I think you need to add this EXTENSION pack:

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "pgcrypto";
```

You can use `uuid_generate_v4()` as well, you'd need to add the EXTENSION pack then:

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";
```

Comment: As of 2022, I can confirm that this works as expected with PostgreSQL if one wants a database-level solution, rather than generating uuid with Python. Are we forced to use a text based fallback, or is there a higher level SQLAlchemy API that supports this?

Comment: You can also use `sa.func.gen_random_uuid()`, which is documented [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/functions.html#sqlalchemy.sql.functions.Function).

Answer (score 0):

We can use `UUIDType`,

```py
from sqlalchemy_utils import UUIDType
from sqlalchemy import String

class User(Base):
    id = Column(UUIDType(binary=False), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    name = Column(String)
```

For more details we can refer to the [official documentation](https://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data_types.html#module-sqlalchemy_utils.types.uuid).

Comment: `uuid.uuid4()` -> `uuid.uuid4` otherwise all elements will have the same UUID

Answer (score -21):

You could try writing a [custom type](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/05/types.html#types_custom), for instance:

```
import sqlalchemy.types as types

class UUID(types.TypeEngine):
    def get_col_spec(self):
        return "uuid"

    def bind_processor(self, dialect):
        def process(value):
            return value
        return process

    def result_processor(self, dialect):
        def process(value):
            return value
        return process

table = Table('foo', meta,
    Column('id', UUID(), primary_key=True),
)
```

Comment: In addition to [Florian's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183042/how-can-i-use-uuids-in-sqlalchemy/188427#188427), there's also [this blog entry](http://blog.sadphaeton.com/2009/01/19/sqlalchemy-recipeuuid-column.html). It looks similar except that it subclasses `types.TypeDecorator` instead of `types.TypeEngine`. Does either approach have an advantage or disadvantage over the other one?

Comment: This doesn't even work, it's just a cut-and-paste job from the dummy type example from the docs. Tom Willis' answer below is much better.

Comment: Doesn't it need a `default=?`?  e.g. `Column('id', UUID(), primary_key=True, default=<someautouuidgeneratingthing>)`

Comment: Link points to "Page not found", https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/custom_types.html#creating-new-types is propably close to the old one