# How to use UUIDs instead of integers in MySQL DB

Tags: python, mysql, uuid

I would like to use python's `uuid()` function to assign my MySQL id's instead of just an integer and `AUTOINCREMENT`.

However, it would also be nice if that `uuid()` was generated when an object is created. I've not worked extensively with SQL before. So, the only way I can see to do this is when a new object is created in the python code, run `uuid()` and just assign it manually, but that seems unnecessary.

Is there a way to integrate this into the MySQL DB?

If so, what datatype do I assign to that column? varchar?

Comment: Why is this tagged Python? Do you want to do this in Python? If so, which module are you using? MySQLdb?

Comment: It's tagged python because `uuid` is the python module I'd like to use in my code. And I'm using Flask-SQLAlchemy, is that a factor?

Comment: You can create a custom UUID sqlalchemy column type as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183042/how-can-i-use-uuids-in-sqlalchemy).

Comment: Why do you want to use a UUID? If the ID is unique within the application what does it matter how long or globally unique it is?

Comment: Not completely, but it sounds like it could become a security concern later on if I'm passing them to and from a site/mobile app via API

Comment: If security is your concern, then you should know that rule one of security is to use a library. If you try and do it yourself you'll mess it up.

Comment: Wouldn't using the uuid library suffice? Or do you mean something different?

Comment: Why use Python's uuid? Just add [MySQL's  `UUID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid) to a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger if your primary key field is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL does not have real UUID support – you can store UUIDs in `CHAR(32)` columns, although your indexes probably won't like it.

[The SQLAlchemy docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/custom_types.html?highlight=uuid#backend-agnostic-guid-type) provide the following recipe for using Python's `uuid` with any database:

```
from sqlalchemy.types import TypeDecorator, CHAR
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import UUID
import uuid

class GUID(TypeDecorator):
    """Platform-independent GUID type.

    Uses Postgresql's UUID type, otherwise uses
    CHAR(32), storing as stringified hex values.

    """
    impl = CHAR

    def load_dialect_impl(self, dialect):
        if dialect.name == 'postgresql':
            return dialect.type_descriptor(UUID())
        else:
            return dialect.type_descriptor(CHAR(32))

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        if value is None:
            return value
        elif dialect.name == 'postgresql':
            return str(value)
        else:
            if not isinstance(value, uuid.UUID):
                return "%.32x" % uuid.UUID(value)
            else:
                # hexstring
                return "%.32x" % value

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        if value is None:
            return value
        else:
            return uuid.UUID(value)
```

By using this snippet, you will also keep the possibility open to switch to Postgres later on, a database which *does* have native UUID support.

As for initializing objects: you are right to assign a new `uuid.uuid4()` when you create a new object; the database (especially a database without UUID support) can't do that for you.