# Inequality in SQLAlchemy query when using SQLModels/Pydantic model with UUID type column mappings (with AzureSQL)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi, uuid, sqlmodel

I am creating a FastAPI application on top of an existing database (AzureSQL), the SQL table `ID` column (primary key) is populated by:
`CONVERT([varchar](36),newid())`

My SQLModel class definition for the table is:

```py
from sqlmodel import Field, SQLModel
from uuid import UUID

class MyItem(SQLModel, table=True):
    id: UUID = Field(primary_key=True, index=True)
```

My issue comes when I query the table for a specific `id`;

```py
@router.get("/{item_id}", response_model=MyItem)
async def get_item(*, item_id: str, session: Session = Depends(get_session)):
    item = session.get(MyItem, item_id)
    if not item:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="Item not found")
    return item
```

If there is a record in the database with ID of `AAAAAAAA-1111-2222-3333-444444444444` (Note: In the SQL table, the UUIDs all appear uppercase), if I hit this URL endpoint with the UUID (upper or lowercase), it will 404; the `session.get(MyItem, item_id)` is returning `None`.
I've tried typing the endpoint with `item_id: UUID`, converting the `item_id` to uppercase and a few other janky solutions; but nothing seems to work.
What does work is if I change the SQLModel `id` type to a `str`, then the query returns a match, i.e.:

```py
class MyItem(SQLModel):
    id: str = Field(primary_key=True, index=True)
```

However, I don't really like it.

Is there a way to use the UUID type and for it to work nicely with SQLModel/SQLAlchemy?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183042/how-can-i-use-uuids-in-sqlalchemy